# Provide generic arguments to DocumentReferences in JsonConverter

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, google-cloud-firestore, json-serializable

I'm using `json_serializable`'s `JSONConverter` interface to convert Firestore's `DocumentReference`s into valid JSON objects.

This is the JSON converter class. It tries to be generic:

```dart
class DocumentSerializer<T>
    implements JsonConverter<DocumentReference<T>, DocumentReference<T>> {
  const DocumentSerializer();

  @override
  DocumentReference<T> fromJson(DocumentReference<T> docRef) => docRef;

  @override
  DocumentReference<T> toJson(DocumentReference<T> docRef) => docRef;
}
```

And this is the usage of the annotation:

```dart
@JsonSerializable(explicitToJson: true)
class Recipe {
  @DocumentSerializer<Recipe>()
  final DocumentReference<Recipe> id;

  @DocumentSerializer<User>()
  final DocumentReference<User> authorId;

  final String title;
  final String description;
  final String imageUrl;
  final List<DocumentReference<User>> likes;
  final List<String> ingredients;
  final List<String> steps;
  .
  .
  .
}
```

Unfortunately, this does not work. The build runner fails when it reaches the first usage of the annotation, which is the `id` field. Is there a way to provide generics to `DocumentReference`s in `JsonConverter` which can be serialized properly?

Answer (score 1):

I found a workaround; albeit less elegant than what I'm aiming for. Turns out separate `JsonConverters` need to be created for each `DocumentReference` type.

For example, if I have an `id` field of type `DocumentReference<Recipe>` for the `Recipe` class , I would need to create the following JSON converter...

```dart
class RecipeSerializer
    implements
        JsonConverter<DocumentReference<Recipe>, DocumentReference<Recipe>> {
  const RecipeSerializer();

  @override
  DocumentReference<Recipe> fromJson(DocumentReference<Recipe> json) => json;

  @override
  DocumentReference<Recipe> toJson(DocumentReference<Recipe> object) => object;
}
```

...and use it as such:

```dart
@JsonSerializable(explicitToJson: true)
class Recipe {
  @RecipeSerializer()
  final DocumentReference<Recipe> id;

  @UserSerializer() // <- same goes for other types
  final DocumentReference<User> authorId;

  final String title;
  final String description;
  final String imageUrl;
  final List<DocumentReference<User>> likes;
  final List<String> ingredients;
  final List<String> steps;
  .
  .
  .
}
```

A bit more verbose, but I'll take it unless someone comes up with a more efficient answer.